# How can I run a command window hidden or minimised?

Tags: command-line-interface, scripting, powershell

I have written a powershell script which generates a "EULA" type popup which the user has to agree to.

It does this at logon by running as a scheduled task for a user (non-admin) account. It needs to run elevated, so I am using the following script to run it elevated:

```
$pw= convertto-securestring "myPassw0rd" -asplaintext –force
$credential = new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential -argumentlist "-default-",$pw
$localArgs = "/c Powershell c:\scripts\myScript.ps1" 

[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("cmd.exe", $localArgs, "Administrator", $credential.Password, $computer)
```

(I will be encrypting the password to make it slightly more secure, but that's not relevant to this question.)

Anyway - my problem is that when the script is called it displays the command prompt window behind my "pretty" EULA popup.

Is there a way to hide / minimise the command window?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Do you want the PowerShell script or the cmd.exe prompt to be hidden?

Comment: Why do you even run a PowerShell script by calling `cmd` which then starts PowerShell? That sounds like at least two levels of indirection too much.

Comment: @Mark - I want the command window to be hidden

Comment: @Johannes - That was the only way I could successfully pass Admin credentials to it, by running the above "wrapper" script

Comment: Taken a look at Start-Process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```
$Process = new-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$Process.StartInfo.UserName="Administrator"
$Process.StartInfo.Password=$Credential.Password
$Process.StartInfo.Domain="$Computer"
$Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle="Hidden"
$Process.StartInfo.FileName="cmd.exe"
$Process.StartInfo.Arguments="$localArgs"
$Process.Start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Start-Process cmdlet (PowerShell 2.0):

Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential $credential -WindowStyle Hidden -WorkingDirectory ... -ArgumentList...

Comment: Think this is 90% there, but am getting " Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters" when I add the -Credential argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use -Credential and -WindowStyle parameters together with PowerShell v2, you either need PowerShell v3 or use -NoNewWindow and -Credential parameters together

You can use the below code for PowerShell v2:

```
$user = "{user}"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "{password}" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
     -argumentlist $user, $pass

start-process -Credential $cred -NoNewWindow powershell "-command & '{path and script}'"
```